# Visio 2010: Moving Multiple Connectors, Sequential Diagram

Tags: visio, message

I am trying to move multiple connectors that connect lifelines of objects, but the connectors become unglued if I select more than one and move them. Is there a way to move all of the selected steps down one or two connections without having to manually reattach one at a time?
This would be very handy in inserting new messages that would go above existing ones.

Comment: To clarify, are you aiming to maintain these connectors on the same objects, just lower down on each object?

Comment: Precisely. So far I've been able to get along by not gluing at all, but this then results in problems if I want to move objects around, or change their spacing.